# how to put numbers next to pictures in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm currently making a simple strategy game in html using css and javascript too. I'm very new to this so this might seem obvious and simple to you all but i'm very confused.

So i have my picture, it's a little pixel battleship i made. I want to have a number show next to that ship to tell how many i have. How do i do that? I assume you have to use css for that right? In the end there are going to be 6 ship types.

Thanks in advance,
Lucas

Comment: Please share your HTML markup, and tell us what have you tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the image in a container with position set to relative. Then put some text inside some tag and position it absoutely

for example

```
<div style="position:relative">
<img src="your image here">
<p style=""position:absolute; right: 0"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use float property of CSS to display text next to an image.
This link might help https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp